# Central Administration test

Tags: central-administration

I would like to expose some additional features in my WebPart when it is added to the Central Administration site.  I tried testing for SPAdministrationSiteType.TenantAdministration, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the magic setting is: SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.IsAdministrationWebApplication